# get .findOrCreate() error

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I'm using `Sequelize` as ORM. Here's my user model:

```
###
    User model
###
User = exports.User =  globals.sequelize.define "User",
    username: globals.Sequelize.STRING
    email:
        type: globals.Sequelize.STRING
        validate:
            isEmail: true
    hash:     globals.Sequelize.STRING
    salt:     globals.Sequelize.STRING(512)
    fname:    globals.Sequelize.STRING
    lname:    globals.Sequelize.STRING
    country:  globals.Sequelize.STRING
```

I'm saving user:

```
globals.models.User.findOrCreate
    username: "johny"
    password: "pass"
    email: "johny93[###]example.com"
.success (user, created)->
    console.log user.values
    res.send 200
.error ->
    console.log err # how to catch this?
    res.send 502
```

If email is valid (email: "johny93@example.com"), everything works great. But if email fails validation (as in the example above), I get an insertion error. How to catch error type? `.error` method can't get any error parameters.

Comment: Can you turn on SQL logs for sequelize. It will give you the query you're trying to run that's causing the error. also @Sriharsha is correct that you need to specifiy the args string in order to console.log the error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sequelize will pass the error as the paramater to the error function.

**JavaScript**:

```
User.findOrCreate({username: "johny",password: "pass",email: "johny93[###]example.com"})
.success(function(user, created){
    console.log(user.values);
    res.send(200);
})
.error(function(err){
   console.log('Error occured' + err);
})
```

**CoffeScript**:

```
globals.models.User.findOrCreate
    username: "johny"
    password: "pass"
    email: "johny93[###]example.com"
.success (user, created)->
    console.log user.values
    res.send 200
.error (error)->
    console.log error # how to catch this?
    res.send 502
```

Comment: thank you, I can't explain why it had not worked for me before. For example as error I get a string `Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'coreNumber' at row 1`. How can I get smth like error code and row id? I need this to handle input errors automatically to show error for user. Or will it be better to validate input before insertion to DB manually?

Comment: Are you looking for a regex that will pull ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD and row 1 out of that error string?

Answer (score 14):

```
 User.findOrCreate({
  where: {
    username: "johny",
    password: "pass",
    email: "johny93[###]example.com"
  },
  defaults: {
    //properties to be created 
  }
}).then(function(user){
  var created = user[1];
  user = user[0];
  console.log(user.values);
}).fail(function(err){
   console.log('Error occured', err);
});
```

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/Upgrading-to-2.0

EDIT: as @Domi pointed out, better way is to use 'spread' instead of 'then'

```
User.findOrCreate({
  where: {
    username: "johny",
    password: "pass",
    email: "johny93[###]example.com"
  },
  defaults: {
    //properties to be created 
  }
}).spread(function(user, created){
  console.log(user.values);
}).fail(function(err){
   console.log('Error occured', err);
});
```

Comment: According to the link you shared, this code works, but it's not the recommended way to work with methods that return multiple arguments. You can use `spread(user, created)` instead of `then(userAndCreatedInOneArray)` with `findOrCreate`, to save you working with the array you call `user` (but is really not the user).

Answer (score 4):

Sequelize 2.0 changes syntax and would now be

```
User.findOrCreate({
  where: {
    username: 'johny',
    password: 'pass',
    email: 'johny93[###]example.com'
  }
}).then(function (user) {
  res.send(200);
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
  res.send(502);
});
```

Comment: In Sequelize 3.0, it is recommended to user .spread() http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/model/#findorcreateoptions-promiseinstance-created