# How to Handle Errors When Using the .create(...) Method in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

Hi **sequelize** experts!

I would like to ask, how to handle errors when using the method `.create(...)`. I found posts both in the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/instances/) and in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003148/sequelize-get-findorcreate-error) on how to handle errors for the `.build()` and `findOrCreate()` methods but not for the `create()` method.

Comments are highly appreciated.

Note:
I am using **sequelize v3.1.0** and **tedious v1.11.0**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All async actions in sequelize returns a [promise](https://promisesaplus.com/)

A promise is an object with some mehods that will be invoked, based on whether the async action succeeded or not

```
Model.create/findOrCreate/update/whatever.then(function () {
  // Will be invoked on success
}).catch(function () {
  // Will be invoked on failure
});
```